# NoSuchMethodException problem with reflection

Tags: java, reflection

So, I've got something along the lines of:

```
public abstract class myClass {  
  String myString;
  int test;

  public myClass(String heuristic) {
     mystring = heuristic;
     test = heuristicSwitch();
  }

  public int heuristicSwitch() {
     int hTest = 0;

     try {
        String methodName = "getHeuristic" + myString;
        Method actionMethod = myClass.class.getDeclaredMethod(methodName);
        hTest = (Integer)actionMethod.invoke(this);
     }
     catch(Exception e) {
     }

     return hTest;
  }

  public int getHeuristicManhattan() {
     return 100;
  }
```

}

I'm stumped... I keep getting `NoSuchMethodException`, but I've no idea why. I thought the problem might have been that myClass is abstract so I tried this with getClass() and had the same exception, so I'm thinking it's something else (unless this doesn't find superclass  methods?). Thoughts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try using `getMethod()` instead of `getDeclaredMethod`.  the former restricts you to the specific class instance, the latter includes the whole hierarchy.  Also, i assume the heuristic (e.g. "Manhattan") is capitalized appropriately?

that said, something like this is probably much better handled through the use of enums and some sort of internal strategy class.  you then map your enums to the relevant strategy implementation.

Comment: That did the trick, thanks! I'll vote up as soon as it lets me.

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be:

`String methodName = "getHeuristic" + mystring;`

But i don't know how yours compiles.  What is the variable 'heuristic' that is in scope there?

Comment: np :) btw, I guess this wouldn't compile if you were using `private` fields everywhere, which is generally good practice.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use a library such as commons-beanutils rather than struggling with the unpleasantness of direct reflection.

Also, your sample code has an empty catch block, which is best avoided.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you're variable `myString` isn't set to what it should be.  I would insert some debug statement to make sure `methodName` is exactly what you think it should be.